# How to intercept execve() via exec* wrapper calls using LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: c, process, posix, instrumentation, ld-preload

I am trying to intercept `execve()` via `execl()`. Here's my wrapper call (built as a shared library — `libexec.so`).

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

static int (*real_exec)(const char*, char *const [], char *const []) = 0;
static void __attribute__((constructor))init(void) {
    real_exec = (int (*)(const char*, char *const [], char *const []))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "execve");
}

int execve(const char* arg, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]) {
    printf ("In wrapped execve\n");
    return (*real_exec)(arg, argv, envp); 
}
```

and here's my program that execs.

```c
//run.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {    
    int pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        execl("/usr/bin/date", "date", NULL);
    } else {
        wait (NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

AFAIK, all other `exec*` calls are wrapper over `execve()` system call. I also validated the program above by running with strace.

```
> strace -f -e execve ./run
execve("./run", ["./run"], 0x7ffcefad6a28 /* 61 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 1491914 attached
[pid 1491914] execve("/usr/bin/date", ["date"], 0x7fff28393cc8 /* 61 vars */) = 0
Tuesday 16 February 2021 12:52:16 PM UTC
[pid 1491914] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1491914, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

But when I run the program the following way,

```
> LD_PRELOAD=/home/user/libexec.so ./run
```

the call is not getting intercepted. i.e I don't see `In wrapped execve\n` getting printed.
What am I missing here? If I instead directly call `execve()` in `run.c`, it works.

Secondly, does `LD_PRELOAD` also follow child processes? Are the calls made by the children and descendents also intercepted?

Comment: `AFAIK, all other exec* calls are wrapper over execve() system call. I also validated the program above by running with strace.` - not neccessarely. Library functions can call system call by using `syscall` directly, without calling its wrapper function from the library. And `strace` shows you actual syscalls, not library functions called.

Comment: Do you mean `execl()` -> `syscall(<number for execve>,  ...)`  instead of `execl()` -> `execve()` -> `syscall(<number for execve>,  ...)`?

Comment: Exactly, but to be sure you need to check source of your standard library

Comment: Thanks. Also, is there a way to intercept calls from forked processes (children)?

Comment: Sure, just add `LD_PRELOAD=yourlib.so` using `putenv()` before calling `exec()`

Comment: I'm a starter and I don't know much about this stuff but I have a question, why in the first code you have `execl` but in the second one you got `execv`?

Answer (score -1):

Short Answer: The issue is that with the above implemented 'libexec' will only intercepted execve calls between the main program to execve. Calls inside 'libc' between execl and execve will not be intercepted to the libexec wrapper.

Long Answer:
With LD_LIBRARY_PATH=libexec.so, the following calling tree is established: "main" -> "libexec.so" -> "libc.so". Calls from "main" will be intercepted by libexec, but calls inside "libc.so" (e.g., execl -> execve) are not intercepted (by default).

The solution is to add a wrapper to "execl" to the libexec.so, following the same structure as the execve wrapper already implemented.

Comment: Thanks, Is this specific  to `libc.so` ? Because I have also tried this with secondory calls to `malloc()`  (built a wrapper shared library  for `malloc` - `libmalloc.so` and used it with `LD_PRELOAD` )  where my program is calling some function of a real shared library (against which it is dynamically linked) and that function  calls `malloc()` (i checked the source code of that function) and it worked.

Comment: This is not correct. If you intercept `malloc`, for example, and call `printf` from your own `malloc` implementation, you program will crash with stack overflow because `printf` calls `malloc` internally, and it will call your custom version of `malloc`, not a library one.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But that's not the point here. My program was only calling  a function from the shared library and in my `malloc` wrapper there was no `printf` .it was straight away returning `NULL`, causing the library function to fail in my program.

Comment: It was a comment to @dash-o, that his answer is incorrect

Comment: @qrdl, ah ok, If you could add  your comment as an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: It was just an idea, I'm not sure how standard library works in this way on your platform (I guess it is GNU standard C library on Linux), so I don't think it is fit to be an answer.